# Exception when installing Magento 2 from CLI

Tags: magento2, installation

I am trying to migrate my Magento 1 to 2 and for that I want to create some complete startup scripts to completely start over. Installing Magento2 using the web works fine, but when I try to run this command:

```
bin/magento setup:uninstall

bin/magento setup:install --db-host localhost --db-name m2 
    --db-user magento --db-password ******* --db-prefix exa_ 
    --base-url http://m2.example.com:2000/ --language en_US 
    --timezone Europe/Amsterdam --currency EUR --admin-user bart 
    --admin-password ******** --admin-email bart@example.com 
    --admin-firstname Bart --admin-lastname Friederichs 
    --backend-frontname admin_exa
```

It gives me this error:

```
  [Zend_Db_Statement_Exception]                                                                   
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'm2.exa_store_website' doesn't exist  
  , query was: SELECT `exa_store_website`.* FROM `exa_store_website`
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are any 3rd party modules present that add console commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know exactly what was wrong, but adding `--clean-database` fixed it.

Comment: You mean: --cleanup-database

Answer (score 0):

I think the error code answers itself.

```
Table 'm2.exa_store_website' doesn't exist
```

Comment: I see that yes, but I haven't created that table myself. I uninstall en re-install, shouldn't that 'just work' ? I added `--cleanup-database` to my command and it seems to work now though ....